# Abrir nova janela no javascript sem foco

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando abrir uma nova janela sem perder o foco da principal porém não funciona:

```
function openUrl() {
  window.open(url);
  window.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Tradução)
Resposta original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133755/8858168)

O que você procura é chamado de janela "pop-under"

- Abra uma nova janela usando `var handle = window.open()`
- Perca o foco da nova janela usando `handle.blur()`
- O foco de retorno para sua janela existente usando `window.focus()`

No entanto, não é uma garantia, pois as configurações do navegador do usuário podem substituir esse comportamento, especialmente os bloqueadores de pop-up.

---

Eu fiz testes locais, e realmente vai ter um grande problema com bloqueador de pop-up, minha sugestão é abrir abas.